# Need Clarity How to solve the Zipperdown Vulnerability issue on Cordova IOS?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

**I've successfully created the Cordova iOS app, then I move into production, but my app has a security issue on**

```
Zipper down Vulnerability leading to Remote Code Execution Attack

ZipperDown attack launches a Man-in-the-Middle (MiTM) attack and replaces the benign .zip file with a malicious .zip file
over the unencrypted network.
The app uses the ZipArchive or SSZipArchive library to decompress it. Since the ZipArchive and SSZipArchive libraries
allow unzipping files in parent directories, malicious .zip files can be unzipped to overwrite app data or codes. Apps that
dynamically load the codes, such as via JavaScript bridges, make it easier for an attacker to overwrite the codes and
launch remote code execution attacks
```

*I did not have any idea about this issue, How to find and solve this issue?*

Comment: What Cordova plugins are you using?

Comment: @AaronMeese  Cordova Platform -> ios 6.2.0, and I'm Using These plugins, 
Cordova-plugin-in-app browser 5.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-iosrtc 8.0.1 "iosrtc"
Cordova-plugin-network-information 3.0.0 "Network Information"
info.androidbcd.plugins.custom 1.0.0 "CordovaCustomPlugin" -> I've created also custom plugin